# Storybook - How to pass separate args to children component and modify them through controls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have an `Accordion` component that has `Accordion.Item` as children. `Accordion.Item` can have props such as `size` etc. How to I pass props seperate props just for children items so that I could visually control them through storybook UI?

```
export const AlternativesSizes: TStory = {
  args: {
    spacing: 'sm',
    variant: 'alternative',
    hasBackgroundColor: true,
  },
  render: (args) => (
    <Accordion {...args}>
      <Accordion.Item
        id="story-17"
        title="This accordion is size 'large'"
        size="large"
      >
        <Text>
          This is the expanded content for an accordion item <b>#1</b>.{' '}
          <i>
            Here you can use various HTML <sup>tags</sup>{' '}
          </i>
          <b>
            <a href="https://cooppank.ee">And even links</a>
          </b>
          <br />
          <ul>
            <li>Use lists and other various elements</li>
            <li>Use lists and other various elements</li>
            <li>Use lists and other various elements</li>
          </ul>
        </Text>
      </Accordion.Item>
      <Accordion.Item
        id="story-18"
        title="This accordion is size 'small'"
        size="small"
      >
        This is the expanded content for an accordion item #2
      </Accordion.Item>
    </Accordion>
  ),
};
```

As you can see I have passe size='large' manually as a prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use such a structure?

```js
  args: {
    spacing: 'sm',
    variant: 'alternative',
    hasBackgroundColor: true,
    items: [
      {
        id: 'story-17',
        title: "This accordion is size 'large'",
        size: 'large'
      },
      {
        id: 'story-18',
        title: "This accordion is size 'small'",
        size: 'small'
      }
    ]
  },
```

And apply it such:

```js
  render: (args) => (
    <Accordion {...args}>
      {args.items.map(item => 
        <Accordion.Item
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          title={item.title}
          size={item.size}
        >
          //...
        </Accordion.Item>
      )}
    </Accordion>
  ),
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I don't know why I didn't thought of that